# how to pass dynamic value in void() react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to pass dynamic value in company.

```
 const getAllEntities = () => {
    dispatch(
      getEntities({
        page: paginationState.activePage - 1,
        size: paginationState.itemsPerPage,
        sort: `${paginationState.sort},${paginationState.order}`,
        company: 'tcs',
      })
    );
  };

export const getEntities = createAsyncThunk('employee/fetch_entity_list', async ({ page, size, sort, company}IQueryParams) => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/${"employees-list"}/**${company}**`;
  return axios.get<IEmployee[]>(requestUrl);
});
```

Comment: Please be descriptive about the question. I didn't understand anything other than you are working for tcs company

Comment: It's unclear what specifically you are asking for help with. Can you [edit] the post to clarify what "pass dynamic value in company" means? This may require adding/editing a more complete [mcve].

Comment: I think all you want is for `getAllEntities` to take the `company` as an argument?  `const getAllEntities = (company: string) => { ...`